# ANGULAR InvalidValueError: Map: Expected mapDiv of type HTMLElement but was passed null

Tags: angular, typescript, google-maps

I have this problem when trying to initialize google maps.
As you can see Im trying to load the map in this div but I always get the same message.

tried using

`ngAfterViewInit()`

because I thought maybe the view doesn't finish loading before the function is called but it didn't help.

**Error Message** (same as title) -

```
Uncaught (in promise): InvalidValueError: Map: Expected mapDiv of type HTMLElement but was passed null.
```

my code:

**map.component.ts** -

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { Loader } from "@googlemaps/js-api-loader";
import { GoogleMapsService } from "src/app/Services/GoogleMapsService/google-maps.service";

@Component({
  selector: "app-maps",
  templateUrl: "./maps.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./maps.component.scss"],
})
export class MapsComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() inputVal: HTMLInputElement;

  constructor(private googlemapsService: GoogleMapsService) {}
  loader = new Loader({
    apiKey: API_KEY,
    version: "weekly",
  });

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log("YO");
  }
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.loader.load().then(this.googlemapsService.initMap);
  }
}
```

**googlemaps.service.ts** -

```
Import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

let map: google.maps.Map;

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root",
})
export class GoogleMapsService {
  constructor() {}

  initMap() {
    const mapOptions = {
      // center: this.userCenter,
      zoom: 8,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,

      panControl: true,
      mapTypeControl: false,
      panControlOptions: {
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_CENTER,
      },
      zoomControl: true,
      zoomControlOptions: {
        style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE,
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_CENTER,
      },
      scaleControl: false,
      streetViewControl: false,
    };
    const userCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742, -0.12085);

    const userCenterMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: userCenter,
    });
    userCenterMarker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
    map = new google.maps.Map(
      document.getElementById("map") as HTMLElement,
      mapOptions
    );
  }
}
```

**maps.component.html** -

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="inputVal" />

<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: The this.googlemapsService.initMap is confusing. It is supposed to be an object? If so, in your implementation of the service, it is a function, in which case it should be called with a (), and which should return a value too

Comment: When Im calling it as a function and returning the "map" variable I get the following message : 

`Argument of type 'Map<HTMLElement>' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: typeof google) => typeof google | PromiseLike<typeof google>'.
  Type 'Map<HTMLElement>' provides no match for the signature '(value: typeof google): typeof google | PromiseLike<typeof google>'.`

I have a hard time figuring out the type I should pass to the initMap func.
tried passing it like this `initMap(): HTMLDivElement` 
same problem.

Comment: Instead of a service a custom directive makes more sense here as you are trying to manupulate the DOM

Comment: @VimalPatel can you elaborate a little? Im aware of directives, how would it help ? thank you!

Comment: @NirGraziani What I meant of course is that you should also modify your service's initMap() function to make it return an object (**map** in your case, I suppose)

Answer (score 1):

The API can be loaded when the component is actually used by using the Angular HttpClient jsonp method to make sure that the component doesn't load until after the API has loaded.

Try looking at [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-akszvj?file=src/app/map.component.ts). If that doesn't spark something, maybe share a stackblitz of your own.